How can I change stock level of products?
I'm using Drupal 10 and commerce 2 with commerce_stock module.
I tried to edit product stock level with loading a variation and set it to my api number.
$variation->set('field_stock', '5');
$variation->save();

when I dump the variation, the field_stock returns 5 but in edit page of variation it's still the last number. based on my search I found out product stock is transaction based and it does not work like this.
Is there a way to programmatically update the stock level of a product ?
